# Solaris : Sort numerical values

Tags: shell-script, shell, python, solaris, sort

I have a file with following values.

```
keyword1 19.02 1.69.94
keyword2 19.01 1.68.118
keyword3 19.02 1.69.119
keyword4 19.01 1.68.115
keyword5 19.02 1.69.304
keyword6 19.02 1.69.39
```

I want these to be sorted based on 3rd column.

In Linux, the following command using version sort works.

```
raj@VirtualBox:$ grep 19.02 file.txt | sort -t ' ' -k3 -V
keyword6 19.02 1.69.39
keyword1 19.02 1.69.94
keyword3 19.02 1.69.119
keyword5 19.02 1.69.304
```

On Unix(Solaris) the version sort seems to be missing. I searched around for working alternative on Solaris, but couldn't find one.

I can also use a solution in python.

Comment: Note that the `-V` option to `sort` in your `grep 19.02 file.txt | sort -t ' ' -k3 -V` example is a non-standard, non-portable GNU extension to [the POSIX `sort` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try reversing the fields and using `.` as the field separator:

```
awk '{print $3,$2,$1}' your_file |
   sort -nt. -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 |
   awk '{print $3,$2,$1}'
```

Also, my solaris system has GNU sort (same as in linux) in `/usr/gnu/bin/sort` and I don't remember having ever installed it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned `python` - the following is a python2 solution that will hopefully work in whatever python2 version exists on your Solaris machine

```
lines = open('file.txt').readlines()
lines = [l.split() for l in lines]
lines = [line for line in lines if line[1] == "19.02"]
def sorter(x):
    z = x[-1].split(".")
    return x[0], x[1], [int(y) for y in z]

lines.sort(key=sorter)
for line in lines:
    print " ".join(line)
```